# Recognize language in Microsoft Office

Tags: language, microsoft-office-2010

Can Microsoft Office recognize input language automatically?

I'm thinking it in a way as it works e.g. in Google Translate: just give a piece of text for it and it gives back most probable language.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-automatic-language-options-194d309c-3e10-4bd5-a694-ba9bbdf4a28e#__toc311028921), *theoretically* Word and Outlook can (I've not seen that in action yet), there is a checkbox on the Language dialog (`Review` tab - `Language` group - `Set Proofing Language` - `Detect language automatically`). But for this you have to download and install LIPs (Language Interface Packs) [from here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Office-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1). As I've made out, the languages not listed on that page, can be downloaded only after you bought them...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, "theoretically", I've that check-box marked, but even after typing five sentences it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: But do you have the LIPs, on what you want to recognize the language of the text? Without them it unambiguously won't work.. What languages do you have installed in `File` - `Settings` - `Language`? Anyway did you checked the important note in the article? ("Before using the Detect language automatically option with a language that you haven't previously used in Office, you must enable the language in the Set the editing, display, or Help language preferences dialog box.")

Comment: Yes, all are installed and enabled in the preferences box.